# Disapearing images

Tags: android, android-activity, android-imageview

okay nice and simple:

Im supposed to be getting this: 
[image]

but for some magical reason im getting this: 
[image]

test code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingTop="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dislike" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

same thing happends with "real code":

```
  <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/counters"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/views_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/views_img"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:background="#FFFF"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_views" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/views_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/views_img"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:text="27,547"
                    android:textColor="#000" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/likes_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/views_layout">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/likes_img"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:background="#FFFF"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_like" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/likes_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/likes_img"
                    android:text="1,232"
                    android:textColor="#000" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/dislikes_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/likes_layout">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/dislikes_img"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:background="#FFFF"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dislike" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dislikes_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dislikes_img"
                    android:text="112"
                    android:textColor="#000" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!--title and desc-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/title_and_desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fucking amazing video!!!!"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc_txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/title_txt"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat." />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Activity at at this point is nearly all commented out since i cant figure this thing out so i doubt that it has anything to do with it

possibly conflicts? dependencies

```
{
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
//        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
//    })
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev182-1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.20.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove "+" in this line of your ImageButton in your layout:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
```

Because "+" should be use only on "android:id" parameter to assign an id to a view

With this extra "+" layout_below should be failing to correct positioning the button below the image.

Another possibility is try replacing all "app:srcCompat" by "android:src” since you're not using any vector drawables.

Comment: Thumbs up for noticing that!!! (i have o idea why it autocompleted it like that) but anyways, it did not solve the issue ;( .....(i havent tested it with "test code", only real one)

Comment: So, try replacing all "app:srcCompat" by "android:src” since you're not using any vector drawables.

Comment: YAY, that was the issue!! THX for your help. (tho, you should edit "Awnser" and add  this "fix")

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in your build.gradle file

```
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

Comment: nope, dosent seem to work. I forgot to mention, it happends only in that one activity